# How to find $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ when both number in front and exponent have fractions?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, exponentiation

I'm not sure how to solve this: $\frac{5}{9}x^\frac{2}{3}$. I applied the product rule and have $\frac{2}{3}\frac{5}{9}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$.

$\frac{30}{9}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$, then  $\frac{9}{30}x^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

This isn't the answer in the book, though. Is the procedure for getting rid of a negative in the exponent to flip the number in front of $x$?

Comment: $$\frac23\cdot\frac59 = \frac{10}{27}$$

Comment: You're multiplying the fractions wrong. $\frac23\times\frac59$ is $\frac{10}{27}$, not $\frac{30}9$.

Comment: And even so, it's _certainly_ not right to invert the _coefficient_ in front of $x^{-1/3}$ when you negate the exponent. That's not a matter of fractions -- if you have, for example, $42 x^{-3}$, that is the same as $\frac{42}{x^3}$, not $\frac{1}{42} x^3$. The number you multiply $x^{-1/3}$ by does _not_ change just because you express $x^{-1/3}$ in a different way -- such as $\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}$.

Comment: Wouldn't that be $\frac{10}{27}x^\frac{1}{3}$? Wouldn't it then simplify to $\frac{27}{10}x^\frac{1}/{3}$?

Comment: The exponent only applies to the $x$, not to the number out front. There would have to be grouping symbols (parentheses) to extend the scope of the exponent. As a rule, expressions like $ab^c$ implicitly mean $(a)\cdot(b^c)$, not $(a\cdot b)^c$ when no explicit grouping symbols are present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments have already pointed out where you have misunderstood this question.

However, as an answer to your question:

\begin{align*}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Bigg(\frac{5}{9}x^\frac{2}{3} \Bigg)&= \frac{5}{9}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x^\frac{2}{3})\\
&= \frac{5}{9}\Bigg(\frac{2}{3}\Bigg)x^{\frac{2}{3}-1}\\
&= \frac{10}{27}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}
\end{align*}